# Kohana query builder update

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-db

Hello, I am building queries with Kohana Query Builder, and I'm trying to get this kind of query:

```
UPDATE `report_count` SET `report_count`=  report_count + 1;
```

What i have right now is:

```
DB::update('report_count')->set(array('report_count' => 'report_count + 1'));
```

And it outputs this query:

```
UPDATE `report_count` SET `report_count` = 'report_count + 1'
```

So my problem is that it puts `' '` around `report_count + 1`. How can I remove these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use an *expression object*. Kohana's query builder lets you create expressions with [`DB::expr`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/api/DB#expr).

The query builder will normally escape all its input, as you'd want it to, but text supplied as an expression object will be included in the query as-is.

The example given in the [documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/database/query/builder#database-expressions) is basically your exact situation:

```
$query = DB::update('users')->set(array('login_count' => DB::expr('`login_count` + 1')))->where('id', '=', $id);
```

This generates a query like the following (the `id` value of 45 is just an example):

```
UPDATE `users` SET `login_count` = `login_count` + 1 WHERE `id` = 45
```